# What kind of grammar is it in 「恥を恥とも感じない」?

Tags: grammar

恥を感じない means "not feel shame" so my question is

> What is the purpose of 恥とも in 「恥を恥とも感じない」? Is it an adverb?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

`AをBと感じる` means `to feel A as B`. Thus `恥を恥と感じない` means `don't feel shame as shame`. The も particle is just here to emphasize the statement (so here とも is just と＋も)

Let's combine that altogether:

> 恥を恥とも感じない
>   (He) doesn't even feel shame as shame

This is not a good a translation but I think it's enough to understand the grammar at hand.